# Scroll web page by iPad movement

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiwebview, augmented-reality

Is there a way to scroll website in UIWebView by iPad movement on x-axis? I want to have something like slider on the wall with glued iPad on it. When I'll move iPad to the right side web page should scroll as well. Same for left side.

I've tried different techniques to achieve it including accelerometer, NFC reader (NFC stickers were glued on the wall) and some methods from ARkit but none of them worked. Have I missed something or is it impossible?

Comment: Interesting question ... but incomplete. If you have tried with CoreMotion, post your code and explain what is not working.

Comment: There is a topic on SOF which proves that you can't achieve it with accelerometer